# Using Cakephp Forms with special character encoding

Tags: php, cakephp, character-encoding

I'm starting to use cakephp and i still have some doubts. Precisely about the .ctp files. After research, i found they are template files used to phpcake to read php code. But what about the encoding. I tested this code in a file with "Utf-8 without bom" codification", but browsers still can't recognize letters like "ç" or "ã" contained in the following example:

```
<!-- File: /app/View/Posts/add.ctp -->

<h1>Add Post</h1>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Post');
echo $this->Form->input('Nome Produto');
echo $this->Form->input('Código Produto');
echo $this->Form->input('Versão');
echo $this->Form->input('Data');
//echo $this->Form->input('body', array('rows' => '3'));
echo $this->Form->end('Criar Ficha');
?>
```

There is some particular configuration i need to add to this ctp files to avoid this codification problems?

P.S. Problem solved. The Form->input was created wrong. Should have been:

```
echo $this->Form->input('cod_produto', array('label' => 'Código Produto:'));
```

since the first parameter is the name of the field in the bd. Thanks mark for all the help!

Comment: you should only use a-zA-z0-9_ for your database field names! and the first arg for input() is the field name.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the following line into your `default.ctp` template file (or whatever template file your whole site is using).  This should set the encoding of the whole site no matter which page you are on:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

Comment: I looked at default.cpt file in folder view/layouts and i have there the following line:
<?php echo $this->Html->charset(); ?>

which is supposed to do that based on waht is said on book cake.

Comment: Look at your HTML source in a browser and double check that a meta tag is actually printed out.

Comment: It is:
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> <title>
  CakePHP: the rapid development php framework:
  Posts </title>
 <link href="/cake/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="icon" /><link href="/cake/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cake/css/cake.generic.css" /></head>

Comment: @user1511579 I just updated my answer.  Try using an `iso-8859-1` encoding instead of UTF-8.  I just copy and pasted your code into a dev project, and it worked.

Comment: still not working. Hmm, i will check, i must be doing something wrong, even with utf8 was supposed to work i guess :/

Comment: somehting is not right, because i have ctp pages without the encoding problem, and others it him

Comment: @user1511579 It didn't work with the `iso-8859-1` character encoding?  What browser/OS are you using?  I have tested it on FF and IE 7, 8, and 9 on Win7.  Using UTF-8 encoding, the characters did not work.  Using iso-8859-1, the characters did.

Comment: I ahve something more strange than that. Using utf8 or iso in folder views/laoyu default.ctp the problem remains.

But the strange is that on my Post folder (where i have my views) the "index" one doesn't have encoding problems. However, when i click on a button on her and change the view page, the second view have encoding problems.

Comment: it has to do with this:
$this->Form->input - the encoding problem has to do with this syntax

Comment: I see you are using CakePHP 1.3+.  I was using 1.2.  Maybe this will help?  `$this->Form->create('Post', array('encoding' => 'iso-8859-1'));`

Comment: Is it the label where the characters aren't showing in, or is it the input element that the characters aren't showing in?  Not sure what else to try at this point, sorry.

Comment: The label. No problem, i will try figure it out.

Comment: That's what I thought.  Sorry.  I am out of ideas.  :(  Hope you are able to figure it out, though.  Somewhere, an encoding is being changed.

Comment: Solved Kyle. I stated the solution in the main post.

Comment: @user1511579 Wonderful.  I am glad you were able to figure it out.